# Trying to create an Eraser Paint for canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

I am creating a drawing app that utilizes the DrawingSurfaceView class below.  In that class i have a Paint Called eraserPaint that the user can toggle on and off..  When on that paint is suppose to eraser what ever is in its path.  but instead its just drawing a black line..

When i save out the canvas as a transparent png the eraser is correct but on the screen it shows black..

**Screenshot from phone of EraserPaint used to write "Erik" on blob**

[image]

**Saved out PNG from canvas**
[image]

**eraserPaint looks like this:**

```
eraserPaint = new Paint();
        eraserPaint.setAlpha(0);
        eraserPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        eraserPaint.setStrokeWidth(60);
        eraserPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        eraserPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
        eraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        eraserPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

**the WHOLE class**

```
     public KNDrawingSurfaceView(Context c, float width, float height, KNSketchBookActivity parent) {

        super(c);

        myWidth = width;
        myHeight = height;

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) myWidth, (int) myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        _parent = parent;


        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);


        tile = new Paint();

        tileImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.checkerpattern);
        shader = new BitmapShader(tileImage, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        tile.setShader(shader);


        mPath = new Path();
        eraserPaint = new Paint();
        eraserPaint.setAlpha(0x00);
        eraserPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        eraserPaint.setStrokeWidth(60);
        eraserPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        //eraserPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
        eraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        eraserPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);



        mCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight, tile);

        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (!_parent.isDrawerOpen()&&mPaint!=null) {
            Log.v("onDraw:", "curent paths size:" + paths.size());

            //mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            //canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            for (int i=0;i< paths.size();i++) {
                tempPaint =  paints.get(i);
                eraserPaint.setStrokeWidth(tempPaint.getStrokeWidth());
                if(fills.get(i)){
                    tempPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                    eraserPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                }else{
                    tempPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                    eraserPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                }
                if(erasers.get(i)){
                    //tempPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                    canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), eraserPaint);
                }else{
                    //tempPaint.setXfermode(null);
                    canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), tempPaint);
                }
                //canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), tempPaint);
            }
            if(_parent.toggleFill.isChecked()){
               mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE); 
               eraserPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

            }else{
               mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
               eraserPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            }
            if(_parent.toggleErase.isChecked()){
               //mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                 canvas.drawPath(mPath, eraserPaint);
            }else{
                //mPaint.setXfermode(null);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            }
            //canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }
    }

    public void onClickUndo() {

        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            undonePaints.add(paints.remove(paints.size() - 1));
            undoneFills.add(fills.remove(fills.size() - 1));
            undoneErasers.add(erasers.remove(erasers.size() - 1));
            clearCanvasCache();
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
    }

    public void onClickRedo() {

        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
            paints.add(undonePaints.remove(undonePaints.size() - 1));
            fills.add(undoneFills.remove(undoneFills.size() - 1));
            erasers.add(undoneErasers.remove(undoneErasers.size() - 1));
            clearCanvasCache();
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
    }

    public void onClickClear() {

        paths.clear();
        paints.clear();
        fills.clear();
        erasers.clear();
        undoneFills.clear();
        undonePaths.clear();
        undonePaints.clear();
        undoneErasers.clear();
        clearCanvasCache();
        invalidate();
        _parent.checkButtonStates();
    }

    public void saveDrawing() {

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        String fileName = "tempTag";
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + fileName + ".png");

            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

    }

    private float mX, mY;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

        undonePaths.clear();
        undonePaints.clear();
        undoneFills.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);

        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {

        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {

        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        if(_parent.toggleErase.isChecked()){
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, eraserPaint);
            erasers.add(true);
            paints.add(eraserPaint);
        }else{
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            erasers.add(false);
            paints.add(mPaint);
        }

        // kill this so we don't double draw

        paths.add(mPath);


        if(_parent.toggleFill.isChecked()){
            fills.add(true);
        }else{
            fills.add(false);
        }
        if(_parent.toggleErase.isChecked()){
            erasers.add(true);
        }else{
            erasers.add(false);
        }


        _parent.checkButtonStates();
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(mPaint==null &&!_parent._showingAlert){
            _parent.showNoPaintAlert();
        }

        if (!_parent.isDrawerOpen()&&mPaint!=null) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            if (x > myWidth) {
                x = myWidth;

            }
            if (y > myHeight) {
                y = myHeight;

            }
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void clearCanvasCache() {

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) myWidth, (int) myHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }
}
```

I should add that i am adding this Custom View to a relative layout that has that checkered pattern as the background image..

PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE help..  i need that preview image to NOT show black after an eraser paint was used.. i need it to show the checkered pattern behind.. I know the eraser is working as those black eraser marks save out as transparent.

**NEW NOTE**

I was playing around and discovered something else thats curious.  Experimenting, i tried switching from drawing to the `canvas` as passed to the `onDraw` method and directly to the canvas i set up in the contructor called `mCanvas`  and noticed it did not draw as far as i could see.. so I added a log  to the `onDraw`  like so:

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       Log.v("DRAWING SURFACE", "canvas:"+canvas+" mCanvas:"+mCanvas);
```

which spits out

```
06-21 11:10:43.994: V/DRAWING SURFACE(4532): canvas:android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@42a8c030 mCanvas:android.graphics.Canvas@431df180
```

Comment: apparently, the black color you saw might be the stroke, cuz it's way too high, maybe you should try to remove it or you can set color of stroke with this also.  eraserPaint.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: Doesn't matter what i do to the stroke size or the color..  same results.. i believe that whats happening is that it is working buit for some reason the eraser is cutting right through everything and is black.. CANT fix it!

Comment: hımm, tried to change paint style ? change it to FILL rather than STROKE ?

Comment: yup!  im so confused!

Comment: Sorry about commenting on such an old one but did you find a way?

Comment: how to implement it???

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem with my app.  I even tried the "finger paint" example code and still had the same problem.  I was never able to have the eraser work as a path, but I was able to find a workaround.  Rather than drawing a path when I erase, I draw a circle (It could be any shape) when the user puts his finger down or there is a "move" event:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(25);
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                    PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, mPaint);
            isErase = true;
            invalidate();
        }
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   
        if(isErase)
        {
            mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, 20, mPaint);
        }
        else{
            touch_move(x, y);
        }invalidate();
        break;
```

It will take some time to incorporate this into your code, but I guarantee you it will take less time than the amount of time you have already spent trying to fix this problem.  I can send you more of my PaintView if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: i will give this a shot.. did you see the note i just added above?  any idea why the canvas being passed to onDraw is different than mCanvas?

Comment: Tried it.. and same result

Comment: Its painting black only

Answer (score 1):

Same problem encountered, tried all other solutions found, no luck.

But I got a workaround. You can add a bitmap to store the strokes.

```
    public void init(int width, int height) {
    Log.i(TAG,"init with "+width+"x"+height);
    foreground = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
    cacheCanvas = new Canvas();
    cacheCanvas.setBitmap(foreground);
}
```

Whenever there is any touch, record the stroke with the current paint and current stroke width. (the paint could be any color, including the eraser paint)

And then override the onDraw(Canvas) method. As the bitmap supports eraser while the canvas doesn't, we can first draw the resultant image on the bitmap first, and then draw the bitmap to the canvas.

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Log.i(TAG,"onDraw called");
    synchronized (strokes) {
        if (strokes.size() > 0) {
            for (Stroke s : strokes) {
                cacheCanvas.drawPath(s.path, s.color);
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(foreground, 0, 0, null);
            strokes.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

FYI, if the foreground bitmap is very large, the performance will be low. To solve this, we should invalidate only the area which the latest finger touches altered.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess: it could be related to hardware acceleration. Try to disable hardware acceleration. If that helps, you can create a bitmap the size of the view, draw all your stuff to that bitmap, and then draw the bitmap into the view's canvas.

Answer (score 0):

For the canvas to erase and invalidate, you have to set the setXfermode of your canvas to null. check the last line of the code.

```
if(view.getId()==R.id.erase_btn) {

        erase_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onDraw.setErase(true);
            }
        }
}

public void setErase(boolean isErase){
    erase=isErase;
    if(erase) drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

Comment: you'd better explain why he has to do that

Answer (score -2):

You can use a boolean variable while choosing eraser (ie. `isEraser = true`) and in `onDraw()`, you can draw path if it's not eraser.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  if(!isEraser ){
   canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
  }
}
```

Comment: That will just not paint new Shapes, won't "remove" the old ones